# Symfony Forms RepeatedType Convert Key Array To String

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, formbuilder

I'm trying to add a repeated password field to a signup form but the value returns an array of the two field values instead of combining the values to a string.

This code return a string:

```
 ->add('plainPassword',  PasswordType::class)
```

But this one returns an array:

```
 ->add('plainPassword',  RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'Passwords must match.',
                'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']],
                ]
        )
```

Is there a form field option to combine the array values, if they match, to a string?

**Edited**:

```
<div class="row margin-top-md">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-field-wrap">
                        <div class="form-control-title">
                            <label for="form">{{ "Password - Min 8 letters & numbers" | trans }}<span class="red">*</span></label>
                        </div>
                        {{ form_widget(form.user.plainPassword.first) }}
                        {{ form_errors(form.user.plainPassword) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-field-wrap">
                        <div class="form-control-title">
                            <label for="form">{{ "Repeat Password" | trans }}<span class="red">*</span></label>
                        </div>
                        {{ form_widget(form.user.plainPassword.second) }}
                        {{ form_errors(form.user.plainPassword) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with returns? cause the add method returns an instance of FormBuilderInterface. How do you render the fields?

Comment: @flow the user input value returned by the field.

Comment: How do you bind the request afterwards to your form again? Cause when i bind the data to the form ($form->handleRequest($request);) and then dumping the $form->getData() i get only one value

Comment: @flow {{form.user.plainpassword.first}} {{form.user.plainpassword.second}}

Comment: @flow are you getting a string or array? And is it the value of the input?

Comment: i'm getting an object, as for all form fields. isn't something like this missing in your twig template? 
{{ form_row(form.user.plainpassword.first) }}
as you wan't to render your form

Comment: @flow yes you’re right I didn’t include that part here but it’s in my code. So you’re also getting an object instead of a string. That’s my dilemma. What do you get with the first form field example? It should be a string. I’m looking for the same results with the second example.

Comment: Getting also an object when i print it out like this {{ form.user.plainpassword }}. But when i render it with form_row it's also properly rendered. Why is this a dilemma? Is it possible that you post more code? cause it's really hard to understand what your problem is.

Comment: @flow i just added the twig code. Again, if I use a single password field the input is passed as a string but if I use the RepeatedType with 2 input fields they are passed as an array. I would like them combined to a string.

Comment: is the problem that you have to access it with first and second? 
you can also do this {{ form_widget(form.user.plainPassword) }}. Then both fields are rendered at once

Comment: No my question is not about the rendering of the fields. My question is about how the field handles the input values. For the RepeatedType field the input is returned as an array but I need a string.

Comment: What are you trying to do and how? You say you get an object but there's no clear indication as of where. In the view? In a controller? As @Flow pointed out `$form->getData()` works, so does `$form->get('password')->getData()` if you want just the field value and not the whole object.

Comment: @msg the question is clear. The return value from the repeatedtype field returns an array. Removing the repeatedtype parameter returns a string.

Comment: @msg in the controller. The variable plainPassword is an array of the two password fields instead of validating the two passwords and returning a string.

Comment: So where's the controller code? We've given you two options that should work. You should post a [mcve].

Comment: @msg I’m a beginner so forgive me. I tried to keep the example as simple as possible because it seems some people get excited to downvote instead of actually helping. After submitting the form the response has a variable plainPassword which is then processed and save to a my user table. If the plainPassword returns a string then it convert the plainPassword and saves it successfully but because the repeatedpassword returns an array I get an error stating password cannot be null.

Comment: @msg you’re overthinking this. I want a way for the form field to combine the two field values to a single string if they match. just dump the values to the view you’ll see two values. Let’s keep it simple. There are a million ways to access values in an object but I don’t want an object. I want to know if there is an option for the form field to do this work.

Comment: @msg appreciate your time.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this password string? Where do you want to use it? In the frontend or in the backend?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

Form

```
...
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;

$builder->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
 'type' => PasswordType::class,
 'invalid_message' => 'xxx',
 'required'          => true,
 'constraints' => [
   new Regex("/^[a-zA-Z0-9-._!#&?£$%\/']{10,12}$/"),
   new NotBlank(
    [
     'message' => "xxx",
    ]
   )
 ],
 'first_name'        => 'password',
 'second_name'       => 'passwordConfirm',
])
```

Template
check in the inspector the name of the password and passwordConfirm fields in your form created by twig (form.user.password ?)

```
{{form_start(form)}}
 <div>
  {{ form_row(form.user.password) }}
 </div>
 <div>
  {{ form_row(form.user.passwordConfirm) }}
 </div>

 <input type="submit" value="ok" class="btn btnAction"> 

{{form_end(form)}}
```

Comment: And what object type does the form field return when submitted?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question?
Is your form linked to an entity. In your case probably User: private $ password (type: string)

Comment: Correct but the object I get is an array instead of a string.

Comment: This is a special field “group”, that creates two identical fields whose values must match.Upon a successful form submit, the value entered into both of the “password” fields becomes the data of the password key. In other words, even though two fields are actually rendered, the end data from the form is just the single value (usually a string) that you need.Validation¶
One of the key features of the repeated field is internal validation (you don’t need to do anything to set this up) that forces the two fields to have a matching value

Comment: Understood but my question is, is their an option for this field to return a string of 1 value if the inputted values match?